Equation of quadratic form, $SAS^T=s_1$, where $s_1$ is the first element of $S$.
Can you give me some ways prove that the equation of quadratic form $$SAS^T=s_1$$ has positive solution ($s_i$ are all positive), where $s_1$ is the first element of $$S=(s_1,...,s_n).$$ Here $A$ is symmetric and invertible.

This is false. Take $n=2$, $S=(s_1,s_2)$ and
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 \cr 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $SAS^T=-2(s_1^2+s_2^2)$ is negative, so cannot be equal to $s_1$, which is positive.

It would be nice to formally define what is $S$.

@CroCo $S$ is the vector $S=(s_1,\ldots ,s_n)\in K^n$.
